# How to wait for style to change in javascript

Tags: javascript

Am trying to get a value from a div which appears after click a button

```
async function pollVisibility() {

  try {
    document.querySelector("#contact_methods > li").click()

    if (!$("#contact_methods > li > div > span").is(":visible")) {

      return document.querySelector("#contact_methods > li > div > strong").innerText

    } else {
      setTimeout(pollVisibility, 100);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

and later I call it like ...

```
 let telephone = await pollVisibility();
```

but I still get the old value (befor clicking)

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to do this with a simple event listener on the element you're waiting for to change? That's what event listeners are for. Polling on an arbitrary CSS selector can be quite expensive, slowing down your code. Especially if it becomes a habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tweak your current code, promisify the setTimeout, and then return the recursive call of `pollVisibility`:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
async function pollVisibility() {
  try {
    document.querySelector("#contact_methods > li").click()
    if (!$("#contact_methods > li > div > span").is(":visible")) {
      return document.querySelector("#contact_methods > li > div > strong").innerText
    } else {
      return delay(100).then(pollVisibility);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

The `try`/`catch` is quite odd though - if that's your full, true code, it would be better to explicitly test to see if the elements in question exist first, rather than running code that may result in an error being thrown.

Unless your actual code also has `await` in it, there's no need for the function to be `async` either. (to make sure the returned value is a Promise on the first iteration, wrap it in `Promise.resolve`)

Comment: nice, works now, can you please explain why my code wasn't working ?

Comment: Your original code wasn't recursive. You weren't returning anything other than the text (if found), so `pollVisibility` always returned either the text found initially, or nothing at all.